# Possible Leak when reading content?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I created a tool which iterates through all Commits of a repository.

Then it makes a diff of the commit to all of its parents and then reads the content for some checks.

Now it came out that this slows down very quickly. It always slows down after the same specific commit which is quite large as it is a merge commit.

Here the code how I iteratre through the commits. The following codes are a little simplified for a better focus.

```
  var repo = new Repository(path);

            foreach (LibGit2Sharp.Commit commit in repo.Commits)
            {
                IEnumerable<FileChanges> changed = repo.GetChangedToAllParents(commit);

                var files = ResolveChangeFileInfos(changed);

                var entry = new Commit(commit.Id.ToString(), commit.Author.Email, commit.Committer.When, commit.Message, files);
                yield return entry;
            }
```

in `GetChagedToAllParents` I  basically make a diff foreach parent like this

```
foreach(var parent in commit.parent)
{
       var options = new CompareOptions
        {
            Algorithm = DiffAlgorithm.Minimal,
            IncludeUnmodified = false
        };

        var patches = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree, options); // Difference
}
```

and later I read the content of the files in this way:

```
       var blob = repo.Lookup<Blob>(patchEntry.Oid.Sha); // Find blob

        Stream contentStream = blob.GetContentStream();
        string result = null;
        using (var tr = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            result = tr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Are there any known issues ? am I missing any leaks?

**Update**

I Found out that most of the time (about 90%) is taken by the diff. and it gets constantly slower

```
 var options = new CompareOptions
            {
                Algorithm = DiffAlgorithm.Minimal,
                IncludeUnmodified = false
            };

            var patches = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree, options); // Difference
```

I can reproduce it with this code:

var repo = new Repository(path);

```
        foreach (var commit in repo.Commits)
        {
            pos++;

            if (pos%100 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pos);
            }
            var options = new CompareOptions
            {
                Algorithm = DiffAlgorithm.Minimal,
                IncludeUnmodified = false,
                Similarity = new SimilarityOptions
                {
                    RenameDetectionMode = RenameDetectionMode.None,
                    WhitespaceMode = WhitespaceMode.IgnoreAllWhitespace
                }
            };

            foreach (var parent in commit.Parents)
            {
                var changedFiles=
                    repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree, options).ToList();
            }
        }
```

it reserved about 500MB for each 1000 commits and at some point it just crashes.  So I posted it also here:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1359

**Is there a faster way to get all files that were changed in a specific commit?**

Comment: A long blocking IO operation isn't necessarily an indication of a leak, it is usually a sign of a long blocking IO operation (tautology intentional.) You might consider processing the commits in parallel.

Comment: I found out right now that the time is consumed by the diff (I update the post) but i don't unerstand why this slows down